# WordPress: Denying users access to dashboard but allowing AJAX requests?

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I would like to deny users the ability to access the wordpress dashboard. But, I want to allow users to use Front End PM which uses AJAX for sending messages between users.

How can I allow the PMs but deny all access to the dashboard?

The classic functions.php approach:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_dashboard_access_handler');

function my_custom_dashboard_access_handler() {

   // Check if the current page is an admin page
   // && and ensure that this is not an ajax call
   if ( is_admin() && !( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ){

      //Get all capabilities of the current user
      $user = get_userdata( get_current_user_id() );
      $caps = ( is_object( $user) ) ? array_keys($user->allcaps) : array();

      //All capabilities/roles listed here are not able to see the dashboard
      $block_access_to = array('subscriber', 'contributor', 'my-custom-role', 'my-custom-capability');

      if(array_intersect($block_access_to, $caps)) {
         wp_redirect( home_url() );
         exit;
      }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, this will redirect from AJAX... thoughts?

If I use User Role Editor... can users access the dashboard?

Essentially, only allow admins to access the dashboard... without limiting AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
function sm_restrict_admin_with_redirect() {

if( defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX ) {
        //Allow ajax calls
        return;
  }


  if( ! current_user_can( "manage_options" ) ) {
       //Redirect to main page if the user has no "manage_options" capability
       wp_redirect( get_site_url() );
       exit;
  }
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'sm_restrict_admin_with_redirect', 1 );
```